# Como enviar Cookies a un Navegador con NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, express

Tengo un Backend en NodeJS, en el cual quiero verificar el inicio de sesión de un usuario. Al validar que el correo y la contraseña ingresados en mi frontend en Angular son correctos, envío una cookie con un token para autenticación de usuario. Cuando estaba realizando las pruebas a nivel local la cookie se creaba y la podia leer de la manera correcta.

Hoy decidí subir el Backend a Google Cloud Console en el cual pude hacer el deploy del servidor de manera correcta. Cuando estaba haciendo las pruebas locales en el frontend con este servidor, me verifica el inicio de sesión pero no me crea la Cookie por lo cual el usuario no puede terminar accediendo al sistema.

Esta es la manera en la que realizo la función para validar el usuario y crear la Cookie:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res)  => {
const correo = req.body.correo;
const password = req.body.password;

// const empleado = null;
empleadoInfo.selectInfoEmpleado(correo, (result) => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.length > 0) {
        if (result[0].contraseña === password) {
            const token = jwt.sign({numeroEmpleado:result[0].numero_empleado}, process.env.JWT_SECRETO , {expiresIn: '12h'});
            // res.cookie('authcookie',token,{maxAge:60000,httpOnly:true});

            // Send cookie to client
            res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `authcookie=${token}`);

            if(result[0].Roles_Solvencia_id_Rol === 3){
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Login correcto Moderador',
                    status: 200,
                    rol: 3,
                    token: token
                });
            }
            if(result[0].Roles_Solvencia_id_Rol === 5){
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Login correcto Capturador de Datos',
                    status: 200,
                    rol: 5, 
                    token: token
                });
            }
        } else if(result[0].estado === 0){
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Usuario inactivo',
                status: 401,
            });
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Contraseña incorrecta',
                status: 401,
            });
            res.end();
        }
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Usuario no existe',
            status: 401,
        });
    }
});
```

});

En el frontend trabajo con peticiones a través de Axios con el valor WithCredentials igual a true.

El res.status(200) funciona ya que en el frontend me aparece la información que envío, pero la Cookie no se crea por mas que lo intente. ¿Cual podría ser el error?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

Comment: Intente hacerlo con cookie-parser y tampoco funciono

Comment: No sé qué versión de Express usas, pero para establecer las cabeceras se usa `res.set()` y `res.header()`. Has intentado así?

Answer (score 0):

Justamente tuve el mismo problema que presentas, en mi servidor instalé cors y lo configuré de la siguiente forma:

```
const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials:true,
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type,Authorization',
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

La cookie la estoy creando igual que en tu ejemplo.

En el cliente que tengo de Next también estoy utilizando axios y tengo configurado las withCredentials por default.

Esta fue la forma que me funcionó para enviar cookies del servidor al cliente por el método post.